# Codeigniter CSRF issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, security

Something very strange is happening, I have enabled CSRF in codeigniter config but using burp suite this can be bypassed.

I'm using the function form_open() for my form and its added the hidden field into the form correctly.

Using burp suite I capture the packet and remove the csrf cookie and post value.

The server still processes the update even though the csrf details aren't in the header sent.

I've attached an Image.

Thanks in advance
Ian

[Header Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyvYt.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqUTj.png

** UPDATE **

```
`$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE; 
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrftoken'; 
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrfcname'; 
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200; 
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE; 
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('account/ajax_log_custom_doc_download');`
```

** FIXED **
I have found the issue and it was that $this->csrf_show_error(); wasn't actually processing the 403 header so it was letting the csrf attack through.

The fix is to add your own header code and die the script, it would be better practice to extend the security class and then add this code.

```
http_response_code(403);
die("Forbidden");
```

Comment: Share your config.php file CSRF section. Also I see the csrf token in the image you shared. Did you mean to share another image?

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply, i have updated my questions with the config file, i have tried turning regenerate to FALSE and it does the same thing. The image attached was just to show what was being sent. Ian

Comment: Right I get the purpose of the image, but I see the csrf token being sent so I'm not sure why you think it would fail.

Comment: HI ALex,

You can change the values in the posted data and it submits without the token being there, so CodeIgniter isn't checking for the csrf token before it processes the update.

Comment: We've had a pen test conducted and they found it.

Comment: I'm aware that one can change post values but that doesn't explain the fact that I see the necessary token information in the image provided. That being said, I feel as though your testing methodology is flawed given what I just said and given that a) this would be a reported problem after so many iterations of CI b) I've looked through ci's code regarding csrf and it is improbable that (if enabled) CI would "process" without the token. If I were you, and if you truly want an answer, I would make a test case following the MVCE principle on stack so that others can replicate....

Comment: ... and explain your testing methodology point by point. This way we can test it independently and determine if it is a testing error or an actual CI error (which would be huge).

Comment: Also, for reference, please see the implementation on `csrf_verify()` (function checks token or outputs error and halts script execution) on line 157 of `Input.php` which according to `CodeIgniter.php` is loaded after the security class and before any actual "user scripts" begin precluding the possibility that anything would get "processed" unless the token is correctly set. Barring any issues in the actual `csrf_verify()` function (which again, hasn't be reported).

Comment: Hi Alex, If you read my original comment it explains how I tested including the software not sure what you're talking about when you say step by step, I never said it was a CI issue I was asking for ideas. I have no sorted this and the issue was the csrf_verify() wasn't killing the process even though it fell into the failure check. Your tone of message really sounds like i've bothered you asking this question, apologies for this i was confused as I've used CI for many projects and hadn't seen this before.

Comment: Please don't mistake my tone for argumentative or otherwise bothered. I'm merely trying to get more information out of you so that I can replicate the issue. All I wanted was a test case and a clearer explanation of your testing methodology. According to your update you believe you found an error with ci? CIs `csrf_show_error` uses CIs `show_error` function which sets the header and exits (explicitly)... It's the backbone of all error reporting in CI. I suggest you report this on the ci forums if you believe there is an error there and please link me on it so I can follow its progress.